# kubectl command to patch a specific attribute in kubernetes storage class

Tags: kubernetes

I have the below Kubernetes storage class

```html
Name:            encrypted-gp2
IsDefaultClass:  No
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"allowVolumeExpansion":true,"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"encrypted-gp2"},"parameters":{"encrypted":"true","fsType":"ext4","type":"gp2"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/aws-ebs","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}

Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Parameters:            encrypted=true,fsType=ext4,type=gp2
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     WaitForFirstConsumer
Events:                <none>
```

Now I want to patch this storage class for only ReclaimPolicy attribute so that ReclaimPolicy is switched to Retain

I am looking for a specific patch command in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be short and simple :

```sh
kubectl patch sc encrypted-gp2 -p '{"ReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}'
```

But StorageClass is immutable so you will have to create a new one:

```sh
$ kubectl get sc encrypted-gp2 -o=yaml > sc.yaml
```

Edit the `sc.yaml` and change the reclaim policy ️. Then:

```
$ kubectl replace -f sc.yaml --force
```

Comment: What's the effect when you do this on an existing storage class? What happens to existing volumes?

Comment: Not sure if it's documented anywhere. My guess is that the k8s admission would not let you delete the storageclass until you have deleted all the volumes. I would also test it with a sample storage class. Try to delete the storageclass and create a volume and then create a new storage class with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following command:

`kubectl patch sc test-storage-class -p '{"allowVolumeExpansion": true}'`

It worked fine and did not affect any of the existing PVs, PVCs or pods.
When it ran fine, I executed the following command for my actual use case:

`kubectl patch sc gp2 -p '{"allowVolumeExpansion": true}'`